# Need to click on div to automate in cypress

Tags: cypress

[image: How can I click in div to automate in cypress?]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can select by the text of the button,

```js
cy.contains('Upload in this folder').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of selector and inner text with `contains` for this.

```js
cy.contains('div', 'Upload in this folder').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is button appears in a modal, you'll want search within the modal DOM element so you grab the correct one and not another one that exists in the DOM.

We will us the powerful [`.contains()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Regular-Expression) with a regex as an argument since adding a selector could make it more brittle.

NOTE: I don't see html for your modal so I will use a dummy selector for it in the example below.

```js
// made up modal selector
cy.get('.modal')
  // always good to assert the modal should be visible
  .should('be.visible')
  .contains(/upload in this folder/i)
  // make sure it is visible before clicking
  .should('be.visible')
  .click()
```